# convex hull based on a filed in postgis

Tags: postgis

I have a table of points i want to build a polygon convex hull based on filed in my table,
the filed is text used to describe a ranking for each point the ranking came  after normalization process between tow weights, after the  ranking filed was formed i wanted to build a polygon convex hull for my point based on the ranking filed i created before using postgis.
i tried in quantum_gis " vector>Geo_processing tools > convex hull "it worked good and the results was good as well, my question is it is possible to get the same result using postgis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can get the same result with [ST_ConvexHull](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html). E.g.

```
SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(geom)) FROM points;
```

Comment: Presumably with the addition of group by ranking?